# java.lang.ClassFormatError for CoreNLP model

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm getting the following error when trying to run StanfordCoreNLP:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: 
Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file
edu/stanford/nlp/ling/ValueLabel
```

It occurs when trying to load the following model file:

```
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar -
Loading parser from serialized file
edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ...
```

I'm using the stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models.jar provided with the [main CoreNLP download](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html), but the source (e.g. ValueLabel) is built with the latest from [their GitHub page](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP).  Is it possible the models jar is incompatible with this latest GitHub code?  At any rate, how would I provide the properly (formatted? coded?) englishPCFG model?  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some sample code that is generating this error?  That model loads fine with the code in the main CoreNLP download, which should be identical to whats on GitHub at the moment.  Also what is on your CLASSPATH when you try to run this?

Comment: I agree it should be (functionally) identical, but when I checked out the v3.5.2 commit (`git checkout fabf65fea64e347501e65e8bc78ca1b7a4468d01`) it reads it just fine.  Shouldn't the models jar be in the GitHub repo anyway?  Or is it and I am missing it?

Comment: Ok, hold up -- checked the latest back out and somehow it also loads now.  Not sure what I did to it..?  Sorry for any trouble.